# window.focus() only when source changes

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-desktop-gadgets

I have a desktop gadget which loads an html file from a network folder into it at regular intervals. The interval is there so that when the source is updated, the gadget automatically updates. I would like the gadget to get focus if the source content changes. If I add myGadget.focus(); to the bottom of the script, the gadget comes to the front at every interval. How do I only do this if the date modified changes on the source.html file? Or any other property of the file which indicates that it has been modified. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var t=null;
        var interval=60000;
        function refreshFrame(){
            document.all.myGadget.src="\\\\network folder\\source.html";
            t=setTimeout(refreshFrame,interval);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Uhm, if you want to execute your function more than one time, you should use "document.setInterval()" instead of "document.setTimeout()". Another thing is, where is your break condition?

Comment: Thanks. I am not a Java programmer so any help is appreciated. Is a break condition for errors loading the source file? I would appreciate help with that.

Comment: 1st: Java != Javascript 2nd: You have generated an endless loop. In case you don't need more code then it is fine.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I did mean Javascript. I would appreciate assistance with an error handler. If the file cannot be found, I would like to display a message like "Source file cannot be found".

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most efficient way of doing it, but you could rely on the fact that the content changed to know if the file has changed.

You could simply store the `innerHTML` value of the frame's document and compare the newly loaded content against the last loaded content.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure how to do that. If you know, please assist or point me in the right direction.

Comment: I read up on innerHTML. I guess that one way of doing it is to remove the setInterval() loop and place a "Refresh" button in my gadget, which will load the new content if it changes. Thanks. I learned something new. My preference is to update the content automatically and bring it to the top only when the content changes.